# unbound method equaldigits() must be called with sut instance as first argument (got int instance instead)

Tags: python, testing, module

I have a module named sut.py and I want to test it by importing it into another file.

```
import logging

class sut:
  logging.basicConfig(filename='run.log',level=logging.INFO)

      def equaldigits(a, b):

        try:
          c = a - b
          return c
          logging.info('%s is the value', str(c))
        except ValueError:
          c = 'Unable to successfully complete execution'
          print c
          logging.info(c)
```

and I have another program to test it, where I want to call the module.

```
import time
import logging
from sut import *

# Test Method
def test(actual, expected):
  if actual == 'Unable to successfully complete execution':
    prefix = ' ERROR '
  elif actual == expected:
    prefix = ' PASS '
  else:
    prefix = '  FAIL '
  print '%s actual: %s expected: %s' % (prefix, repr(actual), repr(expected))


# Provided main() calls the above functions,
# using test() to check if each result is correct or not.
def main():
  print 'SUT'
  start_time = time.time()
  test(sut.equaldigits(0, 0), 0)
  print time.time() - start_time, "seconds"


# Standard boilerplate to call the main() function.
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

But I am getting this issue

```
usxxtomaram1:basic tomara$ ./sut_test.py 
SUT
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sut_test.py", line 45, in <module>
    main()
  File "./sut_test.py", line 39, in main
    test(sut.equaldigits(0, 0), 0)
TypeError: unbound method equaldigits() must be called with sut instance as first argument (got int instance instead)
```

I am just trying to learn python, please help.

Comment: Why did you make the `sut` class?  You never create an instance of it.  Just get rid of it and make `equaldigits` a plain function instead.

Comment: how do I call the function then? I am pretty new to python, please guide me...

Comment: You would just do `import sut` (*not* `from sut import *`) and then `sut.equaldigits(0, 0)`.  If you are new to Python, you should read [the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) to understand the basics before you get in too deep.

Comment: I get this error when I remove the class and call the method directly  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sut_test.py", line 45, in <module>
    main()
  File "./sut_test.py", line 39, in main
    test(sut.equaldigits(0, 0), 0)
NameError: global name 'sut' is not defined

Comment: Hey Yes, I got it. I just tried removing from sut import * and instead put import sut and it worked. I came here and saw the same comment from you. Thank You, you are awesome :)

Comment: Just one issue. I am using a logging statement, it is creating a log file but the file does not have anything, could you please help. I am new to python but know some programming... Just learning to perform some tasks in python

Comment: It's not logging anything because you only use the logging immediately after a `return`, so it never executes.  Again, I suggest you read [the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) and start with simpler tasks.  Later you can ask specific questions about individual problems.  If you don't understand that `return` will end the function and code after it will not run, you need to back up and try some simpler examples to understand how functions work in Python.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand the issue. I will go through this tutorial and then try more problems to work on.

Comment: Please add your comments to answer and then I can mark this post as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code worked after I removed the class name from the sut.py file and also used import sut, as Bren suggested.

Comment: Avoid beginning answers with a question, "Thank you" or some other marker for NAA. That makes it quite likely your answer will be deleted even if it is good.